# Bounce rate always 100% for countries other than India

Tags: bounce-rate

I have a multi regional matrimonial site. I could not understand why my site is facing 100% bounce rate for countries other than India. http://www.getalifepartner.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In taking a look at your site and running it through http://gachecker.com/, it doesn't appear that Google Analytics is installed on every page of your website.  Bounce rate (by default) is a measure of people who looked at one page and didn't do anything else. So, what that 100% bounce rate probably means is people are maybe clicking to other pages, but those pages aren't tracking. Instead, GA only knows about the one page and nothing else, so GA thinks everybody is bouncing away from the one page being tracked.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was worried about the bounce rate. Now I understand my problem.

Comment: One more question please. If I do not install Analytic code in every page, is there any negative effect in seo point of view?

Comment: @rns GA and GA code has nothing to do with search performance. Cheers!!